# 4 Column ListBox selected item to 4 diferent TextBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a userform in VBA, with a 4 column ListBox that imports data from an Excel sheet (this part is working fine).
What I would like is when I selected one of the listbox items the value on the column one of that item appear in a textbox1, the value on the column two appears in a textbox2, the value on the column three appears in a textbox3 and the value on the column four appears in a textbox4.

Thanks

I don't have anything to show here. I am just a Excel VBA noob.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Change`-event routine on your listbox. The data that is displayed in a listbox can be accessed with the property `List`. The selected row can be accessed using the property `ListIndex`:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me.ListBox1
        i = .ListIndex
    
        Me.TextBox1.Text = .List(i, 0)
        Me.TextBox2.Text = .List(i, 1)
        Me.TextBox3.Text = .List(i, 2)
        Me.TextBox4.Text = .List(i, 3)
    End With
End Sub
```