# Search row of cell by selecting a name in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that colletcts data from a excell sheet. when the userform initializes the combobox in it import the names in column "A" from the excell sheet. What I wanted is to select a name from the combobox and the information from the row where that name is (E.g. Selected name is in B4) the textBox1 import the information in cell B5, the textBox2 imports the information in cells B6 and so on.
[image]

Comment: How is this different to your earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016494 ?

Comment: For this i use a combobox with the names. Not a listbox that imports all the information. I tried to use the code from before but it doenst retrieve the information. the column A in the sheet have all the names and for ech name, there is a row with too much information to use a listbox. So i need to search the column "A" by name, and retrieve all the information from the column "B","c","d" and so on of that name only.

Comment: So what is your question? How to figure out the selected value of the listbox? How to do a search with that value into your sheet to get the row number? How to fill your text boxes? All of that is trivial and has been asked and explained many times.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to understand what you want.

> (E.g. Selected name is in **B4**) the textBox1 import the information in
> cell **B5**, the textBox2 imports the information in cells **B6** and so on

**case-A**
It looks like that you want to retrieve the information from the row under the cell where the name is ...

[image]

But from below quote:

> What I wanted is to select a name from the combobox and the
> **information from the row where that name is**

**case-B**
it looks like that you want to retrieve the information from the column beside where the column&row name is. IF name is in cell B4, then you want textbox1 value is cell C4 value, textbox2 value is cell D4, and so on.

[image]

Code for case-A:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
Dim c As Range: Dim i
With ComboBox1
Set c = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 0))
End With
For i = 1 To 3
Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = c.Offset(i, 0)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
End With

With ComboBox1
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .ColumnWidths = "0,25"
End With

For Each cell In rg
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cell.Value
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Code for case-B

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
Dim c As Range: Dim i
With ComboBox1
Set c = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 0))
End With
For i = 1 To 3
Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = c.Offset(0, i)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

With ComboBox1
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .ColumnWidths = "0,25"
End With

For Each cell In rg
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cell.Value
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Name your textbox like this : TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, and so on.
Change the number of loop in the code according to how many textbox you have.

Basically the code "secretly" make a two column combobox, where the first column contains the cell address is hidden (column width is 0).

when the item in the combobox is selected, using the address from the combobox hidden column of the selected item, it fill each textbox with the value.

Please note with this kind of code, you can't skip the column/row value to be displayed in the textbox. Example case-A : when name in cell A1 is selected, you want TextBox1 show cell A2 value and TextBox2 show cell A4 value. Case-B: when name in cell A2 is selected, you want TextBox1 show cell B2 value and TextBox2 show cell D2 value.

Comment: its case B... thanks very much it solved it